# $rootScope in onExit

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope, rootscope

I want to use `$rootScope.$broadcast()` inside `onExit` when state changes.

But for this, I need to inject `$rootScope` in the `.config()`, which is not possible in angular

```
 onExit: function () {
                //onExit is executed when we leave that state and go to another
                $rootScope.$broadcast('broadCastCloseModalStr');
            }
```

Can someone help me to achieve it?

Comment: can you expand your question and describe how are you using the modal? Most modals are resolved as Promises (resolving/rejecting while closing them)

Comment: @varun can you add more code and explain what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`$injector`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) to inject the `$rootScope` into the onExit, like so

```
onExit: function($injector) {
    var rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    console.log("onExit: ", rootScope);
}
```

However, this should also work

```
onExit: function($rootScope) {
    console.log("$rootScope: ", $rootScope)
}
```

Here is a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/WQXRwRQCsRTxHqdgaARS?p=preview)